# Is it possible to tune `fill-paragraph` to balance the lines?

Tags: formatting, fill-paragraph

Inspired by a recent addition of `text-wrap: balance` to CSS I've suddenly realized I'd like to have balanced comments in my code. Current behaviour of `fill-paragraph` (with my current settings) converts this:

```
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
```

to this

```
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
# magna
```

while I'd like it to become more like this:

```
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
# nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
```

Is there any easy way to tune `fill-paragraph` to balance the lines like this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... do you just want to change the `fill-column` ?

Comment: @phils no, `fill-column` stays the same, but the length of all lines is rebalanced to avoid typographic widows, i.e. a single word on a line. With a longer paragraph, line length would be closer to `fill-column`, but could become quite short with two-liners like in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> avoid typographic widows, i.e. a single word on a line.

If you just want to avoid single word lines, then see user option `fill-nobreak-predicate` and its standard option `fill-single-word-nobreak-p` which says "Don't break a line after the first or before the last word of a sentence."

You could undoubtedly adapt that to more custom requirements as well.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the hook to implement something like this.